# DOM Element Not Being Displayed in GTM Variable on Page Load

Tags: dom, google-tag-manager

I'm working on a variable to grab the username of the account that's logged in.  I thought I had it working a few weeks ago using the below setup but it's not currently working.  Any ideas on why it's not pulling in the correct information when the confirmation page loads?

`1`[Website Console View of the Text I want -"Landing_page_test"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GsOn.jpg)
`2`[DOM Element Setup in GTM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKF5N.jpg)
`3`[GTM Debug Mode - Null text displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMtL8.jpg)
`4`[Page Element Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehP8A.jpg)

Comment: You do not show at which event/message you look at the variable in the debugger. You can access DOM elements only after they have been rendered, if you try to use this on page load it will be null (because the element isn't there yet). Might that be the problem?

Comment: That's most likely the reason since it needs to be on page load, rather than a Click, etc.  Any ideas on what options I have to capture that information on page load?

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, you cannot get the information at page load, because the information does not yet exist at this point - usually GTM is integrated in the HEAD tag, and it can access DOM elements only after they have been rendered. There really isn't a way around this, you cannot grab an element that is not yet there.

One workaround that might work for you is to use a visibility trigger. This will trigger an event as soon as the wanted element is in the view port, and you can then access it even if the page has not finished rendering (you can then use your DOM variable, or the built-in Click Element, because "Click Element" in GTM really means "element that has activated the trigger"). This would really only work if the element is in the viewport - there is no built-in "present but not visible" trigger in GTM.

It's probably easier and more reliable to defer you tag until DOM Ready.